# Is it a good idea to model object relations in a program similar to the real-life ones?

Tags: oop, class, relation

Question inspired by a comment to my answer here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55251/separate-classes-communication

Well, if you read the question and answer from the link, there's not mych to add. So I'd like to hear your opinions and (very recommended) examples on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's the beauty of object orientation.

In real life, big things are made up of lots of smaller things. For example a car is made up of wheels, doors, an engine, a steering wheel etc. etc.

Furthermore, you can look at a Ford and a Ferrari and a Smart car and realise that, although they're all different from each other, they're all cars. And you still do things to them like "Start", "Stop", "Turn" etc.

These two features are just real-world examples of what we think of in software development as composition and generalisation. You can very easily imagine a base class `Car` which has a `Wheels` property, a `Doors` property, and so on, and `Start`, `Stop` and `Turn` methods.

I'd go as far as to say that the best object models *should* be based on real-life, tangible, things that people can imagine easily. What better way to make your design understandable than to make it blindingly obvious?